# Evitar doble login

Tags: php, login

Estoy teniendo un inconveniente con el doble logueo. Quiero que, cuando un usuario esté logueado en un navegador y quiera loguearse con la misma cuenta en otro navegador, éste no se lo permita.

¿Cómo puedo llevarlo a cabo en PHP?

Este es mi código de session:

```
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$username = isset($_POST['usuario']) ? addslashes(trim($_POST['usuario'])) : '';
$password = isset($_POST['contrasenia']) ? addslashes(trim($_POST['contrasenia'])) : '';
$errors = array();
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
    // Validar nombre de usuario.
    $query = @mssql_query('SELECT UserID,Pw FROM  PS_UserData.dbo.Users_Master WHERE UserID = \'' . $username . '\'');
    if(empty($username)){
        $errors[] = 'Por favor, proporcione un nombre de usuario.';
    }else if(strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 16){
        $errors[] = 'Nombre de usuario debe tener entre 3 y 16 caracteres de longitud.';
    }else if(ctype_alnum($username) === false){
        //$errors[] = '';//Nombre de usuario debe consistir en números y letras únicamente.;
    }else if (mssql_num_rows($query) == 0){
        $errors[] = 'el usuario no existe';
    }
    // Validar la contraseña de usuario.
    $query2 = @mssql_query('SELECT UserID,Pw FROM  PS_UserData.dbo.Users_Master WHERE UserID = \'' . $username . '\' and PW = \'' . $password . '\'');
    if(empty($password)){
        $errors[] = 'Por favor ingrese su contraseña.';
    }else if(strlen($password) < 3 || strlen($password) > 16){
        $errors[] = 'La contraseña debe tener entre 3 y 16 caracteres de longitud.';
    }else if (mssql_num_rows($query2) == 0){
        $errors[] = 'Por favor, proporcione la contraseña correcta.';
    }
```

Comment: No es una buena idea rechazar el intento de entrada desde una nueva sesión ya que si la sesión antigua se pierde (por limpiar cookies, por usar cookies de sesión con tiempo de vida hasta el cierre del navegador, etc) el usuario no podrá volver a iniciar sesión de ninguna manera. En su lugar te recomiendo que cada vez que inicies sesión en un nuevo navegador la sesión antigua se pierda. Eso podrás implementarlo mediante un campo en la tabla de usuarios que mantenga el SID de la sesión activa, aunque tendrás que comprobar su validez en cada petición (agregarás una consulta SQL por ejecución).

Comment: lo se pero al cerrar el navegador la session se cierra automaticamente y tieneque volver a loguearse.

Comment: No te confundas, la sesión no se cierra automáticamente al cerrar el navegador, únicamente pierdes la cookie que almacena dicha sesión, pero ésta sigue existiendo en el servidor web hasta que el recolector decida eliminarla definitivamente: http://php.net/sessionhandler.gc

Comment: Otra solución que podrías adoptar es guardar el SID de la sesión activa y el último acceso con ella en la tabla de usuarios. Si la SID no coincide (porque estás iniciando sesión en un nuevo navegador o has perdido la cookie) y ha pasado un tiempo superior a X segundos desde el último acceso con la SID antigua puedes permitir el acceso, pero deberás seguir controlando que coincide la SID con la de la tabla de usuarios para evitar que una vez iniciada sesión con el nuevo navegador la vieja sesión se vuelva a reutilizar.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la repuesta OscarGarcia, voy a chekear como puedo llevarlo a cabo y ver que pasa, te mando un saludo

Comment: Debes crear una columna en la tabla de usuario donde cada ves que se loguee se almacene el id de sesion, y cada ves que se haga una petición se debe verificar que el id de sesion coincida con el almacenado de lo contrario se cierre la sesion

Comment: Otra solución es usar el > localStorage del navegador, usando Javascript, para almacenar el id de sessión del usuario, si este no existe en el navegador, significará que debe loggearse de nuevo.

Comment: Una nueva tabla en la que guardes cuando un usuario inicia y cerra la sesión. Al tratar de conectarse de un nuevo navegador y si ya tiene una sessión iniciada se rechaza. Pero habrá un problema al momento de saber cuando "realmente" terminó la sesión actual.

Comment: Eso es exactamente lo que hace una cookie de sesión, almacenar el ID de sesión del usuario.

Comment: Eso de guarda el session_id no funciona siempre actulizara el id con es inicias sesion y hara el update luego al realizar el select por supuesto que es lo mismo nunca va variar no sirve !!!!

Answer (score 2):

Ya que todo el mundo está usando las respuestas para escribir opiniones sin código... yo no voy a ser menos, pero lo haré aportando código.

Lo que te recomiendo es que no bloquees un nuevo intento de inicio de sesión, eso te generará más problemas que ventajas. Céntrate en desechar la sesión antigua y permitir la nueva.

¿Cómo? Lo más sencillo es reutilizar la tabla de usuarios y agregar un campo "SID" en el que almacenarás el SID de la sesión que inició sesión.

**NOTA:** Voy a usar PDO, recuerda que las funciones `mssql_*` están obsoletas y son inseguras.

Tras iniciar sesión y establecer `$_SESSION['UserID']` al valor adecuado guardas el valor de SID en la tabla de usuarios en el campo que has creado para esa función:

```php
<?php
$consulta = $pdo->prepare('
  UPDATE PS_UserData.dbo.Users_Master
    SET SID = :SID
    WHERE UserID = :UserID
');
$consulta->execute([
  ':UserID' => $_SESSION['UserID'],
  ':ID' => SID,
]);
```

Ahora, justo tras establecer la conexión a la base de datos y realizar las comprobaciones de seguridad que tengas implementadas (niveles de acceso, etc) deberás comprobar que el SID coincide:

```php
<?php
$consulta = $pdo->prepare('
  SELECT SID
    FROM PS_UserData.dbo.Users_Master
    WHERE UserID = :UserID
');
$consulta->execute([
  ':UserID' => $_SESSION['UserID'],
]);
$resultado = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($resultado === FALSE) {
  die('Error: ¿¿Usuario no existente??');
}
if ($resultado['SID'] !== SID) {
  /* ¡Es una sesión antigua! Han iniciado sesión en otro equipo,
    invalidamos la información de la sesión actual y reenviamos
    al usuario a la página de entrada */
  unset($_SESSION);
  session_destroy();
  /* Opcionalmente podemos destruir la cookie de sesión */
  header('Location: entrada.php');
  exit();
}
/* A partir de aquí todo va bien, el usuario tiene únicamente
  una sesión activa */
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: hola oscar, nuevamente gracias por su repesta.

Comment: respecto al codigo estoy teniendo un pequeño error de sintanxis  en la la siguiente linea $consulta->execute([
  ':UserID' => $_SESSION['UserID'],  http://image.prntscr.com/image/2555500edf484b7c927a3c560a3c7f04.png  a que podria deberse eso? un saludo

Comment: ¿Qué versión de PHP usas? El soporte para matrices definidas usando corchetes se añadió en la versión 5.4, si usas una versión anterior deberías cambiar "[...]" por "array(...)". En ese caso te recuerdo que la versión más antigua que sigue con soporte es la 5.6, deberías actualizarte: http://php.net/supported-versions , aunque también podría ser culpa de que tu editor de código PHP sea demasiado viejo.

Comment: esa debe ser la razón por la cual no me funciona entonces estoy utilizando PHP Version 5.3.1 necesito realizar varios cambio de los archivos de conexión ya es la ultima version que soporta la conexion mssql_ este inconveniente se me volvio una pesadilla

Answer (score 1):

Espero esto te sirva, lo que a mi me funciona es crear un field en la base de datos que se actualice a 1 cuando el usuario inicie sesión y se actualice a 0 cuando cierre sesión

De esta manera cuando corre la función login verifica que ese field este en 0 y si es así siga adelante con el login y lo actualice a 1, usando esto cuando quieras iniciar sesión en otro navegador se encontrará con que el campo tiene 1 y no continuará, el problema que yo tuve fue con el tiempo de vida default de la cookie o de la sesión ya que si es así cuando se cierre sesión no actualizará la tabla a 0 y no podrás iniciar sesión de nuevo.

Para solucionarlo usa sesiones persistentes y la cookie que expire en un tiempo largo

Ejemplo:

Base de datos:

- id          |   1
- username    |   test
- password    |   12345
- loggedin    |   0  //al registrar al usuario esto debe de ser 0 por default, esto se logra usando 'default' al crear el field en la base
  de datos

Ahora hay que obtener el valor de ese campo usando un query.
Supongamos que la variable asignada a ese campo despues del query es $loggedin

Dentro de la funcion login solo se requiere un IF:

```
if ($loggedin == 0){
  // Continuar con la funcion login y usar un 'UPDATE' para cambiar el valor de 0 a 1

}else{
 // redireccionar a index
}
```

Al momento de cerrar sesion tienes que hacer tambien un 'UPDATE' para cambiar el valor de 1 a 0

Para evitar que la sesion expire y nunca mas puedas acceder puedes revisar estas publicaciones:

[Persistent sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797913/how-do-i-create-persistent-sessions-in-php)
[Cookie never expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290424/set-a-cookie-to-never-expire)

Espero te funcione
Saludos

Comment: Hola @HiramAngeles, puedes agregar un ejemplo? bienvenid@ a SOes!

Comment: Si por cualquier motivo pierdes la cookie de sesión (por caducidad tras varios días, por limpiar las cookies, etc) el usuario se quedaría bloqueado. Peor aún, si se dejó la sesión abierta hace un día, por ejemplo, en el trabajo el viernes y quiere acceder desde casa el sábado por la tarde, tendrá que esperar al lunes para poder llegar al trabajo y cerrar la sesión.

Comment: Listo @Alan, espero este un poco mas claro

Comment: @OscarGarcia estoy de acuerdo contigo, es muy poco funcional ya que solo podras usar el dispositivo en donde iniciaste sesion, pero esta es la respuesta que se me ocurrio a la pregunta inicial

Comment: El problema de modificar y/o comprobar el campo es que pueden producirse condiciones de carrera. Se puede producir el caso en el que se consigan abrir dos sesiones (o más) a la vez. Almacenando el SID garantizamos que sólo una de ellas será válida.

Comment: @OscarGarcia la respuesta que pusiste creo es la más correcta, de esa manera solo se inicia sesión en un solo lugar y la anterior se destruye, gracias! :)

Comment: Gracias @HiramAngeles , recuerda votar positivo la respuesta y/o dar como respuesta aceptada. Si pruebas el código y tienes alguna pregunta no dudes en dejarme un comentario en la respuesta.